# Appending to dictionary stored in dataframe on value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

So I have a DataFrame that looks like the following

```
   a   b   c  
0  AB  10  {a: 2, b: 1}
1  AB  1   {a: 3, b: 2}
2  AC  2   {a: 4, b: 3}
...   
400 BC 4   {a: 1, b: 4}
```

Given another key pair like `{c: 2}` what's the syntax to add this to every value in row c?

```
   a   b   c  
0  AB  10  {a: 2, b: 1, c: 2}
1  AB  1   {a: 3, b: 2, c: 2}
2  AC  2   {a: 4, b: 3, c: 2}
...   
400 BC 4   {a: 1, b: 4, c: 2}
```

I've tried `df['C'] +=, and df['C'].append()`, and `df.C.append`, but neither seem to work.

Comment: `df['C'].update(c=2)`

Comment: This returned a TypeError because 'c' doesn't exist yet in the dictionary.

Comment: `df['c'] = df.c.apply(lambda x: dict(x,c=2))`? Please note that the order of your dictionaries may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generalized way for updating dictionaries in a column with another dictionary, which can be used for multiple keys.

Test dataframe:

```
>>> x = pd.Series([{'a':2,'b':1}])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['c'])
>>> df
                  c
0  {'b': 1, 'a': 2}
```

And just `apply` a lambda function:

```
>>> update_dict = {'c': 2}
>>> df['c'].apply(lambda x: {**x, **update_dict})
0    {'b': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 2}
Name: c, dtype: object
```

Note: this uses the Python3 update dictionary syntax mentioned in an answer to [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression). For Python2, you can use the `merge_two_dicts` function in the top answer. You can use the function definition from that answer and then write:

```
df['c'].apply(lambda x: merge_two_dicts(x, update_dict))
```

Comment: Hm, this is giving me SyntaxError: invalid syntax at the **x part

Comment: Are you using Python2?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I forgot to mention that in the main post.

Comment: Edited with a Python2 solution.